# How do I get most commented posts in disqus?

Tags: php, drupal, disqus

I was looking into disqus api for most commented posts but it leads me to nowhere.
Can somebody share with me how to get thread/posts ordered comment count? Something like this:

```
listPosts.json?orderby=comment_count&order=desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Disqus API](http://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/) seems not to support this directly. But [`threads/list`](http://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/list/) has a `posts` element for each  `response`.

Answer (score 9):

I was dealing with the same issue and the answer is on:

http://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/listPopular/

You can set these parameters...and more...

```
$api_key = 'your_public_key';
$interval = '90d';
$forum = 'your_website_shortname';
$limit = 5;

$url_call = "http://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/listPopular.json?api_key=" . 
            $api_key . "&forum=" . $forum . "&interval=" . 
            $interval . "&limit=" . $limit;

$get_contents = file_get_contents( $url_call ); 

$call = json_decode($get_contents);
```