# How to find most commented article (using disqus)

Tags: django, disqus

I am using [Disqus](http://disqus.com) for commenting on articles in my site. I want to find the most-commented article using the API. Could you provide me with some pointers?

Comment: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1131783-tutorial-get-comment-counts-with-the-api

Comment: Timmy you should have put that as the answer.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony that link does not opens up

Comment: It opens up fine for me

Comment: Duplicate question: [How do I get most commented posts in disqus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646163/how-do-i-get-most-commented-posts-in-disqus).

Answer (score 1):

This API endpoint will load the most-commented articles on your site *within an interval* up to 90 days: http://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/listPopular/

An API request for you would look like this:

`GET https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/listPopular.json?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&forum=YOUR_SHORTNAME&limit=1&interval=90d`

Additionally if you wanted to also get the top comment from that article, you can add `&with_top_post=1`